# How to calculate the size of a record

Tags: sql-server, size, sql-server-2012

How can I calculate the size in bytes (or KB) of one record in SQL-Server tables?
And with one record I mean the row in one table and all its related entities from other tables.

For example, if we have a `Person` table, then a Person, will be a row from the `Person` table and can have several Orders so several rows in `Order` table, one or more Addresses so one or more rows in `Address` table, etc...

Thanks in advance!

**[EDIT]** If it's possible, I'd like an option to exclude columns from the calculation.

Comment: Do you want to include the indexes in the calculation?

Comment: Good question, think both would be nice to know, with and without indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use datalength() function to figure out the size of records ,also can sum it.
eg:    SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(ORDERS))
       FROM PERSON

Comment: That didn't work, error msg: Invalid column name 'ORDERS'. Of course I changed orders to the actual table name i need. But this function asks for a column in stead of a table. Also, there are multiple tables that need to be taken account. Not just one.

Comment: So you can join the tables and then use Datalength function.

Comment: The argument of `DATALENGTH` should be a scalar expression, not a table name. If the row includes columns of different types, you cannot calculate its size with a single `DATALENGTH` call.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was accepted. It's just plain wrong.